# Cleanup taskmeta table of celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) running and everything works nice.

Celery uses by default a database table to store the task results, called `celery_taskmeta`. This table is growing very fast. I read the docs, but I did not find any hint about cleaning up old entries.

Is there a task automatically scheduled by `celerybeat`, that cleans this table up or do I have to configure something here?

**[EDIT]**

Is this related with the [result backend settings](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=meta#celery-result-backend)? This is a bit confusing, because documentation says, there is no default value for this. But it seems, that `database` is the default and it uses the the `default` configuration of normal [Django database configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#databases).

Answer (score 2):

You can manually clean this table this way:

`from djcelery.models import TaskMeta, states
TaskMeta.objects.filter(status=states.SUCCESS).delete()`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the documentation was written after you posted the question.  The page at http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html provides the answer:

> A built-in periodic task will delete the results after [ the time set in the CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES configuration directive ] ... The default is to expire after 1 day.

For a typical Django installation you would set the backend to *database*.  (That's why you are seeing the results stored in the *celery_taskmeta* table of your database.) The configuration directive for this setting looks like:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

I checked my own installation and, sure enough, there is a daily periodic task called *celery.backend_cleanup* which was automatically created when I installed *celery* (or maybe when I installed *django-celery*).

For the periodic task to run I believe you must be running the *celerybeat* daemon/service.

Answer (score 1):

You have read the Celery's documentation.

Django-celery [overrides](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/loaders.py#L34) result backend for you.

Comment: In the [documentation of django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/) nowhere is mentioned, what default settings are done. So reading the documentation of django-celery does not answer the second question and the documentation of celery itself does not answer the main question.

Comment: But your link answers the second question.

Comment: In my case the cleanup task does not work. How to manually trigger it or empty the table in another way?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanup is already done automatically and by default, as already mentioned.
All you need is to update the table size by using this query:
VACUUM FULL celery_taskmeta